# Taurus Blazemter - How to use a function in a body

Tags: blazemeter, taurus

I would like to send a request with a random value or using the current date in the json payload of the request's body in Blazemeter

Example:

```
 method: POST
              url: ${url}/transaction
              headers:
                Content-Type: application/json
              body: {
                "order": {
                  "id": uuidGenerator() + "test" ,
                  "timestamp": datetime( now() , 'yyyy/MM/DDTHH:mm:ssZ')
                }
              }
```

Doc references Test Data Generator Functions:

https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011769877-Test-Data-Generator-Functions-Test-Data-Generator-Functions

Expected

```
 "order": {
                  "id": "7d052488-6fbf-11eb-9439-0242ac130002-test" ,
                  "timestamp": "2021-01-15T18:00:00Z"
                }
```

But

- id value is not interpreted "uuidGenerator() + "test"
- syntax seems to be incorrect for timestamp and card in Blazemter taurus

Answer (score 0):

```
 method: POST
              url: ${url}/transaction
              headers:
                Content-Type: application/json
              body: {
                "order": {
                  "id": "${__UUID()}" ,
                  "timestamp": "${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z',)}"
                }
              }
```

more functions: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time